# Django-SES does not regard DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL in mail_managers

Tags: django, amazon-ses, django-email

I am using `django-ses` to send e-mail using AWS Simple E-mail Service. I have no problem sending using `send_mail()` but from the same e-mail address set in settings, using `mail_managers()` I am getting a `MessageRejected` exception.

Here is a walk-through:

```
$ python manage.py ses_email_address -l
Fetching list of verified emails:
gez@gez.com
```

And via python shell:

```
>>> settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL
'gez@gez.com'
>>> settings.MANAGERS
(('omat', 'om@tekno.org'),)
>>> send_mail('test', 'test', 'gez@gez.com', ['om@tekno.org'])
1
>>> mail_managers('test', 'test')
BotoServerError: BotoServerError: 400 Bad Request
<ErrorResponse xmlns="http://ses.amazonaws.com/doc/2010-12-01/">
  <Error>
    <Type>Sender</Type>
    <Code>MessageRejected</Code>
    <Message>Email address is not verified.</Message>
  </Error>
  <RequestId>66269bb3-ca86-11e1-80db-5b89cf7a6356</RequestId>
</ErrorResponse>
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't caused by `django-ses`. Both `mail_admins` and `mail_managers` use the `SERVER_EMAIL` setting as the From address not `DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/email/#mail-managers

Answer (score 0):

I had some trouble getting error 500 emails raised in Amazon SES.  This procedure may help others.

Things to check:

- It works locally! (I used [django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/email/#console-backend))

  - This means that you can generate an application error and you'll see it in the console of the running server
- [`ADMINS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#std:setting-ADMINS) needs to be defined
- Check that there are no filters which prevent mails being sent when DEBUG=False
- If it doesn't work locally, run a debugger and step through [`AdminEmailHandler`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/_modules/django/utils/log/).  This might clear up why the email doesn't get sent.

If it all works locally, deploy to AWS.

- Check that your application can send email (!), for example:

  - Fire an internal email such as reset password
  - Connect to the app via an EC2 instance and call [`send_email()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/email/)
- Login to the SES console and check that the email has been sent (under 'Sending statistics')
- Trigger a 500 error - sending statistics should also increase, indicating that SES sent an email.
- Is the email received?

  - Check spam folders
  - Is the target email address listed under 'Email addresses' in SES (necessary if your SES account is in the sandbox)
- I had to ensure that [`DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#std:setting-DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL) and [`SERVER_EMAIL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#std:setting-SERVER_EMAIL) were set to email addresses listed as verified in SES